# Discord.net How to get a Guild Amount?

Tags: discord.net

Is there a simple piece of code I can use to get the amount of discord servers/guilds my program is connected to?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a simple piece of code. It would be really helpful to see what you have already tried and where in your code you are trying to get the amount but here is what it would look like:

```
Console.WriteLine(myDiscordClient.Guilds.Count());
```

It will print to console, the amount of guilds your bot is in.